# How do I show or hide texbox based on radiobuttonlist selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I honestly thought this was simple.

I have a radioButtonList with two values, Approved or Rejected.

If the selected Value is Approved, hide the texbox. If rejected is selected, then show the textbox so reasons for rejection could be entered into the box.

I can't get this to work. I tried:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:[name=<%= apr_rej.ClientID %>]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Approved') {
                $('#<%= divReason.ClientID %>').hide();
            } else {
                $('#<%= divReason.ClientID %>').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I got divReason must be declared.

Then I tried:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:[name=<%= apr_rej.ClientID %>]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Approved') {
                $('#divReason').hide();
            } else {
                $('#divReason').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

No errors but not event fired.

Here is the markup:

```
       <tr>
         <td align="left" class="style1" style="border: thin solid #6699FF">
             <h3 style="text-align: left">
                 2.<strong> Select One:</strong></h3>
           </td>
            <td style="border: thin solid #6699FF" class="style5"><asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" 
                    ID="apr_rej" repeatdirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Left" CellPadding="0" 
                    CellSpacing="0" style="font-weight:700; text-align: center;" 
                    Height="21px" Width="406px" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="Approved" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="Rejected" />
               </asp:RadioButtonList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="divReason">
          <td align="left" class="style3" style="border: thin solid #6699FF">
             <h3 class="style4">
3. Enter Comments:</h3>
          </td>
          <td style="border: thin solid #6699FF;font-Weight:bold;" class="style5">Comments:(If this form is Rejected, you must give a reason.)<br />
              <asp:TextBox id="txtreason" runat="server" TextMode ="MultiLine" 
                 style="border: 1px solid #6699FF" BorderColor="White" Height="114px" 
                  Width="574px"></asp:TextBox><br />
         </td>
      </tr>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing name with id in selector you should use id attribute selector with contains wild card. You can not use `ClientID` with `divReason` as it does not have *runat="server"*.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:[id*=<%= apr_rej.ClientID %>]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Approved') {
                $('#divReason').hide();
            } else {
                $('#divReason').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response @Adil but still getting same error:

`'divReason' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Comment: divReason does not have runat="server" so it does not have .ClientID attribute and could be accessed by its id, check my updated answer and tell me what you get then...

Comment: you are right. It was my stupid mistake to have left out runat="server". I added it, tried again and got `Object expected` error. I tried your updated code without CLientID and without runat="server", same `objected expected` error message.

Comment: The problem was that I needed a jquery pluggin. It is working fine now.

Thanks a lot for your help.